# Make exception on hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have a toggle button near an image to show information and click on body to hide everything.
My problem is that when I click on the button it hides my image. So I'd like to know if there is a easy way to make something like "exception".

```
    $("body").click(function(){
      $("img").hide();
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('div').toggle();
    });
```

Here is a Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fbgy0aq9/

Comment: You do not really want's to add a click event to your body, right?

Comment: The code in your fiddle is different from the code in your question.

Comment: Algo : If I could do it with out a body click event, it would be gret.
j08691 : It seems like the codes are identical

Comment: In your fiddle you have two `$("body").click` handlers but above the second is `$('button').click(`

Comment: Deep apalogies. and for sure you were right

Answer (score 0):

When you click on *anything* contained within `body`, the click event will "bubble up" the document and eventually also invoke the click handler on `body` itself.  You can [stop this propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation), [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fbgy0aq9/5/):

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    $('div').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Another approach could be to modify the selector in your `body` click handler to ignore clicks originating from the button, [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fbgy0aq9/4/):

```
$("body").on('click', ':not(button)', function(){
    $("img").hide();
});
```

Comment: Perfectly working in my real conditions ! thanks a lot and thanks for the reading  David !